# Why do API's list JSON elements that could be represented as key-value pairs?

Tags: json, api, rest, formatting

I work with a lot of REST API's and JSON data. I find that most of the time, JSON files are formatted as lists of key-value pairs, but my intuition tells me that there should be a higher-level key so I don't have to iteratively search for an ID or something.

For example, a typical response might look like:

```
{ 'blocks':
  [
    {
     'id': '123eaf456',
     'name': 'example',
      ...
     },
    {
     'id': '987cvr012',
     'name': 'example2',
      ...
     },
     ...
  ]
}
```

When my intuition tells me it should be structured like this, to make it easier to find a specific element:

```
{ 'blocks':
  {
    '123eaf456': {
     'name': 'example',
      ...
     },
    '987cvr012': {,
     'name': 'example2',
      ...
     },
     ...
  }
}
```

I'm sure there's a reason that so much JSON data seems to be structured this way, but I can't seem to find anything on the topic. Does the former structure actually have practical utility, or does it just come down to essentially a stylistic choice?

Answer (score 0):

We are talking about JSON which means JavaScript **Object** Notation. In the notation every object defines in curly braces:

```
{
   
}
```

Every object can have attributes (properties in the notation), which are defined as follows:

```
{
   "attributeName": attributeValue,
}
```

Let us look at your example. We have an object (for example, `an apartment`), and `that apartment` consists of `blocks`, every block has attributes: `id` and `name`. Which is quite logical.

You propose to build the object blocks with attributes: `123eaf456`, `987cvr012`, ... But I would say: it is not an object with logical structure, it is an artificial dataset which complicated for understanding (human brain likes objects).

Let us look at your use case of searching (as I understand you got this object from the server) you want to find something by id, but why you don't ask the server object with a specific id? And you could want to find a block by name, in this case by your logic it should be a structure with the names of keys (not so generic, is not it).

If we are talking about performance of the server, I guess the server finds records in a database and uses JSON, as a presentation of found data, from the database that has no impact on performance.